# Partial data missing from an image file retrieved from MSSQL DB

Tags: php, sql-server, image

I'm trying to show image from DB saved in **Image** field. But I can see only 63KB of image.

This is my code:

```
$sql='SELECT Photo FROM Personel WHERE ID_USER = '.$id;

$result=mssql_query($sql);

$res=mssql_fetch_assoc($result);

header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
echo$res['Photo'];
```

As you can see nothing special, so I think problem in DB or server configuration.

DB installed on Windows XP server.

Actually it's Access control systems DB, and SQL files installed in that program's folder, but don't know this information useful or not.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
Screenshot for Photo field type:
[image: Screenshot of Photo field type]

Comment: How did you uploaded the images to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your comments say that the entire image ***is*** being stored in the DB, it's possible that the issue is related to a data limit / timeout within PHP and / or the webserver.

EDIT: I've left the following part of the answer here for historic info (to show what else we tried) but please see the comments below, as it's more likely that the issue is related to a PHP or webserver config setting, limiting the size of the response data. Still not fully resolved yet.

---

I notice you have a `Content-type` header, but not a `Content-length` header.

You could try adding a `Content-length` header with some arbitrary, known value (e.g. 12288) and see if this affects the size of the file returned (since you know that it's currently 63K - does it change to 12K?)

If it does, then you'll need to get PHP to calculate / find out the actual size of your image and add a Content-length header of that length.

Comment: Didn't think about it. I tried. If I use size smaller than 63K then it's show less info, but if I write size more than 63K then see same as without content-lenght.

Comment: OK. In that case, it's time to look through the PHP and / or webserver docs for default / max content-length settings / script execution times etc. I've looked through my php.ini and can't see anything obvious. Which webserver are you running?

Comment: Probably it apach, I don't have access to it. But I'll ask our system administrator to look into configs. Thank you very much for help. I find in settings **mssql.textlimit = 4096**, looked in internet and it can help. What do you think?

Comment: That setting still sounds like a database setting, and 4096 doesn't match up with 63KB so I don't think it would be that. By all means try changing it to see if it helps but I'd be surprised if it did. If your site is on a publicly-available server, try going to centralops.net/co/DomainDossier.aspx, enter your site domain and check the 'service scan' box. You might get some info on which webserver is running.

Comment: I think this is enough info for our system administrator to find solution. One of all this variants will work:) Thank you again, I'm marking this as right answer!

Answer (score 6):

had the same problem, just run this first:

```
mssql_query('SET TEXTSIZE 10000000'); // sets limit to 10MB
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. It looks like that default TEXTSIZE is set to 63kB (64512B).

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you're using a data type (e.g. `blob`) for the `Photo` field that is too restrictive for the size of images you're trying to save. Each data type has different limits on the amount of data that can be stored in that field.

See [this page in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html) for an example of some different field types and their associated storage capacity / suitability.

The `blob` type, for instance, has a limit of 2^16 bytes (64K).

If your images are larger than that (quite likely), try changing the field type to something like `mediumblob` (2^24 = 16.78MB).

If you're dealing with *really* large images then you may need `longblob` (2^32 = 4.29 GB) instead, but at that stage you're going to have more than just data storage problems :)

Comment: Field has **Image** format, see screenshot (question updated).

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I think we are in right direction. But there is one problem. i can see images in right size from default program of that Access control systems. It means that images in db saved normally, right?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I can see that it shows "16". I'm not sure whether that's 16 bytes, K or MB...

Comment: @Squig You're talking about MySQL but the OP is using SQL Server.

Comment: True. To be honest, I didn't spot that until after I'd posted my examples, and I probably should have been more thorough. My main aim was to check that the OP understood about different data types when storing values in a DB. (63K sounded so close to the 64K limit of a `blob` field.) It's clear that they understand about field types and from their comments, it looks like it's nothing to do with the DB anyway. I don't think it's worth me updating my post, given that the DB route is a red herring, but happy to google and replace my link with one for MSSQL if you think that would help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have limitation on field `Photo`.

Comment: I only found **Size -16** in description, but didn't find how to change it. See screenshot (question updated)

Comment: As far as I know this DataType only contains a pointer to a file, so increasing it's size (if it's possible) won't help you. Try changing your DataType from `Image` to `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: Interesting... It can helps, thank you. I'll try it later, afraid to broke live DB :)