# How to convert hexadecimal into image in php?

Tags: php, image, hex

I have a desktop application. In that application, I stored images as hexadecimal and that's working perfectly. But now I wants to convert the desktop application into web-application in php. While I'm converting that hexadecimal code into the image then that image is not completed means image is cropped from the bottom.

Following is the php code I'm using to render the image

```
    <?php
$image="visit on given link to get the hexadecimal code";   
$bin = pack("H*", $image);
?>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($bin);?>" />
```

The hexadecimal code is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU0tqTlZb-rvQIzT-6yaS8wIKGVlAZK6/view?usp=sharing

And following is the image I'm getting after execute above code

[image]

And the full image is here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z-byehRMIBJqF-GlMGbGFa8hNUKpXn_w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Before start debugging your code, have your client tried open the image in their application again to see that it was saved correctly?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo ($bin);?>" />

Comment: Yes, In the desktop application the same hexadecimal code is working perfectly.

Comment: @BhaveshTailor - You can't echo binary data directly into a `src`-tag. It should be base64 encoded (just like the OP does).

Comment: here is my hexa decimal code  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU0tqTlZb-rvQIzT-6yaS8wIKGVlAZK6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have any CSS that crops the image? Like a container with a max height and overflow hidden? It's pretty hard for us to know what's happening with only the provided info.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I executed the above script  in a single php file. No any css there

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what you need more to understand the issue.

Comment: To start with, it would be good to know what the full image should look like. I tried your code with the hex you provided. I get an image that looks different from what you've posted (what you've posted is not in the image at all).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please try this hexa https://drive.google.com/file/d/15LuPXBZRsejCxMF39wLhvsd2JQOc6S-Y/view?usp=sharing       it's of the above image and full image I'm providing you with in 5 min.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson here is the full image of above hexa  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z-byehRMIBJqF-GlMGbGFa8hNUKpXn_w/view?usp=sharing Please check it.

Comment: header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$data = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD........";
echo base64_decode($data);
In the second case, use this instead:

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $data . '" />';

Comment: @BhaveshTailor Thanx for your response, But it's still not completed image. Had you try and get a complete image?

Comment: With the hex data you linked to and your exact code, I am getting a _completely_ different image, than the one you have shown above - I am getting this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Sr6.jpg

Comment: If the solution is possible in J-query, You can share also that solution.

Comment: dear @BhaveshTailor  hexa is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU0tqTlZb-rvQIzT-6yaS8wIKGVlAZK6/view?usp=sharing and full image is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z-byehRMIBJqF-GlMGbGFa8hNUKpXn_w/view?usp=sharing . actully that was mismatched hex. so sorry..

Comment: @DevendraRajput That is still the incorrect hex, Its still https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Sr6.jpg, If you can send the correct hex, I'll check if I can get the completed Image

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to the above issue after waisting two days. 
Unfortunately, when I was export blob from SQL server without query then I got an incomplete blob. That's why the PHP script cropped the image. But now I exported blob via query and got the complete blob then script is converting blob into image properly. If you are also exporting blob data from SQL server also then you should use the given query. Thanks, @Bhavesh Tailor and @Magnus Eriksson for giving your time.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)

SET @sql = 'BCP "SELECT * FROM [DB].[schema].[table] " QUERYOUT c:\exportdir\exported_table.csv -c -t, -T -S DM-SQL'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I too wasted two days searching for a solution. 
Finally, had success after doing the following
mssql_query('SET TEXTSIZE 10000000'); // sets limit to 10MB
Of course, had to modify this for my php framework, Yii2 in my case. 
Credit to Wizzard. [Partial data missing from an image file retrieved from MSSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350153/partial-data-missing-from-an-image-file-retrieved-from-mssql-db)